# How can i hide the submit button if record not found

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to disable or hide the commandbutton if no record is found.
I have gooogled but could not find the solution.

Here is the code:

```
<p:column>
    <div style="overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
        <p:dataTable var="tPreferences"
            value="#{userPreferences.preferences}"
            emptyMessage="No Questions Found." id="pTable" styleClass="borderless">
            <p:column headerText="PREFERENCES">
                <h:outputText id="sName" styleClass="cellLabelMand"
                    value="#{tPreferences.shortText}" />

                <h:outputText value="&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;" escape="false" />
                <h:selectManyCheckbox id="grid"
                    value="#{tPreferences.preferencesSelectedItem}"
                    layout="grid" columns="1">

                    <f:selectItems value="#{tPreferences.catList}" var="pref" />

                </h:selectManyCheckbox>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </div>
</p:column>
```

CommandButton:

```
<h:commandButton value="Submit" id="btnUserInfo"
    onclick="return openUpdateDialog();"
    actionListener="#{userPreferences.saveUserPreferences}"
    styleClass="richButtonSave" style="background:green;"  
    disabled="#{empty pTable.tPreferences}"   />
```

Comment: Apparently `#{pTable.tPreferences}` is simply not empty. Didn't you actually mean to check `#{userPreferences.preferences}` instead?

Comment: Thanks that worked for me. What if i want to hide the buttion instead of disabling.

Comment: Use `rendered` instead of `disabled`.